# Is Mihawk stronger than one of the gorosei who holds the sword(since mihawk is titled strongest swordsman)?

Tags: one-piece

Since mihawk is titled as the strongest swordsman and there is one samurai in the 5 elders team,so does that mean mihawk is stronger than that gorosei?

Comment: Might I redirect you to this question: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5765/is-dracule-mihawk-really-the-strongest-swordsman?rq=1

Comment: There's no way of telling how strong they are until that Gorosei member shows us some moves. Until then, it's TBA

Comment: Agreed on the TBA with the Gorosei, but note that new info in the Vivre Card Databook indicates Mihawk is equivalent to or stronger than Shanks (in terms of swordplay at least). Hence, this assumption of him being stronger than the gorosei is also not very outlandish.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know because we don't know how strong that Gorosei is or (really) how strong Mihawk is.  Mihawk is likely a better swordsman than anyone in One Piece but that doesn't not mean he is stronger than that Gorosei in any other way.

There are several things to note:

1. Mihawk being the strongest swordsman is as much of a title as a
   display of his ability. If there is a character who is a stronger
   swordsman, it must be that his ability is underestimated or not known
   to the world at large. Zoro won't be the strongest swordsman until
   he can somehow be demonstrated as earning that mantel.  As it is Mihawk's
   defining character trait and Zoro's dream, I doubt Oda has some mystery swordsman somewhere who is stronger with a sword.
2. Mihawk's title only refers to his ability with a sword. It is notable that Mihawk's only power seems to come from his reputation
   and swordmanship. He has no known devil fruit, no shown Haki (though
   he obviously has Armament), no gimmicks, and no crew.  I don't think
   many people would doubt that Shanks is stronger and Shanks uses a
   sword.  Shank's power, however, includes his crew and his insane
   levels of Conquerors Haki.  If Gorosei must be a stronger fighter, he might
   be stronger for other reasons than swordsmanship. That being said:
3. There is no reason to assume the Gorosei members must be all that strong. Maybe he was the strongest but got old. Maybe he was
   never that strong but got there based on his intelligence.

(Also Whitebeard was the strongest man but Kaido is the strongest beast.  Maybe there is a stronger swordswoman somewhere? But that doesn't apply here... probably. Unless that Gorosei is a Celestial so is not to be downplayed to the level of mere "man"."

Comment: The Gorosei are celestials, they are the highest ranking celestial Dragons. So i do agree with you, for some weird reasons they see themselves as a higher race on the level of gods and that coulld explain why the title of "strongest swordsman" might be seen as an insult rather than a compliment.

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin I really hope Oda doesn't pull that. Though it would be satisfying to see Zoro transcend to that even higher level. (I did know they were Dragons but sorry for the odd wording.)